# No plugin found for prefix 'archetype' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] local

Tags: java, maven, build

While I am trying to creating maven project in command prompt, i am facing **build failure** error.I tried by changing proxy setting in still i am getting same build failure error.

please tell where i am doing mistake
[image]

Comment: Sitting behind a proxy?

Comment: i am not getting what your saying @khmarbaise. can please explain how can i modify the settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after researching many possible ways finally i found the problem in my code.
the problem is network guys block the proxy.i tried in my home finally i got build success .thanks you @khmarbaise